# How to remove dots from android studio 2.2 preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

[image]

> Just update 2.1 to 2.2

**when i do code then showing dots in front of code for reference see image.
how can remove this dots...please help !**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance and uncheck "Show whitespaces"

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable that from settings

Go To:-

File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance and uncheck the checkbox "Show whitespaces"

[image]